# Update an entity but not the null value properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a customer which I want to update in the repository.

```
var customer = new Customer{ Name = "Test" }
```

The customer has still more properties which are null, because I have not loaded them before to the client. Thus these properties have all their default values like `null or 0`.

What do I have to do with latest EF 6, that **only the property Name** is updated and the other properties from the customer are not overwritten?

1.) How would I have to query/update the customer?

2.) What would happen if the customer has a **collection** of  and he has changed some properties of some meetings - but not all properties - how would then be the override behavior?

UPDATE pseudo code

```
Open context

Get customer

Close context


Open context

Update customer.name

SAveChanges

Close context
```

The custom.name is not saved, why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your model generated and it has a name of "MyEntities" and you should have a customer ID if you are updating an existing. Here is a solution using c#.

```
using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
    // this will retrieve the customer based on ID
    Customer cust = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerID == custID);

    // you can update each column
    cust.Name = "Test";

    // save the changes to the entity
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: When I do this then the customer is not updated. The problem might be that the customer is retrieved in another context. This context is closed. Then in a new context I updated the customer.Name. But here it does not update. Do I need to call any additional code?

Comment: @Pascal this should work, are you unable to save the updated property using this approach ?

Comment: it works when I do before savechanges => context.entry(customer).state = state.Ismodiffied;

Comment: This should work to retrieve the customer and update it within the same using statement. Could you provide more code to show how you are retrieving it and attempting to update?

Comment: As I wrote above Steve I fetch and update in 2 different context. But see above I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it natively without getting the whole entiy first, which is obviously 2 db hits.

There is however an extension you can use that does what you want:
https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Batch-Update-and-Delete